# Play & JSON Transformations: How to deal with optional input and handle possible failures

Tags: json, scala, playframework

The following `find` method should return any document that matches the specified selection criteria and in case sort them as specified by optional parameter `sort`:

```
class DaoComponent {

  ...

  val toObjectId = (__.json.update((__ \ '_id \ '$oid).json.copyFrom((__ \ 'id).json.pick))
    andThen (__ \ 'id).json.prune
  )

  ...

  def find(selector: JsValue, sort: Option[JsValue]): Future[Seq[A]] = {
    selector.transform(toObjectId).flatMap { s =>
    sort.map(_.transform((__ \ 'ignore).json.prune)).map { o =>

      // how do I get 'o' to be either None or Some(content of JsSuccess)?

      collection.find(s)
        .sort(o.getOrElse(Json.obj())
        .cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](0)
    }.recoverTotal { errors =>
       Future.failed(JsError.toFlatJson(errors))
    }   
  }
}
```

In the code above, let's isolate the line where I need your valuable support:

```
sort.map(_.transform((__ \ 'ignore).json.prune)).map { o =>
```

Optional parameter `sort` has to be transformed only if defined... and this is achieved with `map`. Now the problem is that `transform` returns a `JsResult`, and I want `o` to be either `Some(jsValue)` when optional parameter `sort` is defined and `transform` succeeds, or `None` when `transform` fails or optional parameter `sort` is not defined.

Alternatively, instead of getting `None` when `_.transform` fails, it would be great if I could handle the failure in the `recoverTotal` block.

Comment: Can't you just call `JsResult`'s `asOpt` method to get that `Option`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment -

I think that the right combination of `flatMap` and converting your JsResult `asOpt` will get what you want:

```
sort.flatMap(_.transform((__ \ 'ignore).json.prune).asOpt).map { o =>
  // Code in here only executed iff sort defined and transform succeeds
  ...
}
```

BTW in my tests I couldn't actually get `transform` to "fail" in this case - I think `prune` is quite tolerant if the given JSON is not present. I *could* get it to fail appropriately like this:

```
sort.flatMap(_.transform((__ \ 'ignore).json.pick).asOpt).map { o =>
```